# Evaluate previous line in a text file

Tags: python

I am creating a program to edit a text file using the `fileinput` library. What I want to do is search every line in the text file for a certain string and delete it. But I also want to delete the line above if it contains a different but defined string.

For example, if I want to delete every line that contains the word "dog" but I also want to the delete the line above if it contains the word "cat".

The original text would be:

```
I enjoy animals.
I have 2 fish.
I also have a cat.
I also have a dog.
I do not have a gerbil.
My dog stays inside.
The fish have a tank.
The cat goes outside.
My animals are awesome.
```

The result I want to be:

```
I enjoy animals.
I have 2 fish.
I do not have a gerbil.
The fish have a tank.
The cat goes outside.
My animals are awesome.
```

So I am deleting all the lines with "dog" and also the line with "cat" that is above the line with "dog" but not the line with "cat" that doesn't have a line with "dog" after it.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: how about regex?

Comment: keep the previous line in a variable, when the next line is ok write the last line else skip it?

Comment: it might be easier to look ahead: look for cat instances and check the next line for dogs. seperately look for all other dogs (dogs preceded by cats should already be gone).

Answer (score 1):

```
def dog(line):
    if "dog" in line:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def cat(line):
    if "cat" in line:
        return True
    else:
        return False


saved_lines=[]
last_line=""
for line in lines:
    if dog(line) is False: # Not a dog line
        saved_lines.append(line)

    else:
        if cat(last_line) is True:
            saved_lines=saved_lines[:-1] # Delete the last line from the  saved list
    last_line = line  # At end of loop, refresh last_line to value of current line
```

Rather than performing a delete, here the code selectively copies content into `saved_lines`. If a line has a "dog" then it wont be copied. If a line does have a "dog", then the last line saved is a candidate for removal, on detection of a "cat".

Your content should be saved in the `saved_lines` list variable.

The downside of this method is if your starting list is *huge* (like over 50% of your available RAM), then you're very nearly doubling it by saving a selective copy. But chances are you'll be ok.

Comment: You can return `"dog" in line` no need to condition checks

Comment: That's true, but assuming in real life, there might be a more complex (set of) check(s) required, it can be useful to abstract those check rules out into separate functions.

Comment: @RahulKP I think the point was more that 'if X: return True; else return False' is a verbose way of writing 'return X', rather than not having functions.

Comment: Oh I see - whatever you like/best fits your in-house style guide I suppose - as long as it's clear. But yes, if you want to reduce verbose-ness, great point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this approch,

```
data = ['I enjoy animals.',
        'I have 2 fish.',
        'I also have a cat.',
        'I also have a dog.',
        'I do not have a gerbil.',
        'My dog stays inside.',
        'The fish have a tank.',
        'The cat goes outside.',
        'My animals are awesome.']

check = {'dog': 'cat'}
result = []
for index, item in enumerate(data):
    for k,v in check.items():
        if not k in item:
            result.append(item)
        else:
            if v in data[index-1]:
                result.pop()
 
print(result)
['I enjoy animals.',
 'I have 2 fish.',
 'I do not have a gerbil.',
 'The fish have a tank.',
 'The cat goes outside.',
 'My animals are awesome.']
```

- Check is a `dict` which you can add `N` number of combination checks

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `itertools.pairwise` - you mark the "pair" that you want to exclude and then exclude the problematic lines that make up the pair -

```py
import io
from itertools import pairwise
f_str = '''
I enjoy animals.
I have 2 fish.
I also have a cat.
I also have a dog.
I do not have a gerbil.
My dog stays inside.
The fish have a tank.
The cat goes outside.
My animals are awesome.
'''

remove_indices = [list(pairwise(io.StringIO(f_str))).index(pair) 
                  for pair in list(pairwise(io.StringIO(f_str))) 
                  if 'cat' in pair[0] and 'dog' in pair[1]]

for line_num, line in enumerate(io.StringIO(f_str)):
    if (line_num in remove_indices) or ((line_num - 1) in remove_indices):
        continue
    if 'dog' in line:
        continue
    print(line.strip())
```

**Output**

```
I enjoy animals.
I have 2 fish.
I do not have a gerbil.
The fish have a tank.
The cat goes outside.
My animals are awesome.
```